# Calling .ToString() on editor not returning enum name

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I'm trying to call .ToString() on the editor to get the friendly text for a rule.  Either I'm not configured correctly or perhaps there's a bug, hence why I'm reaching out.

When calling .ToString(), the result looks like:
**Check if Products contain  and Medical.NetworkType_BuiltInNetwork is "Y"**

However, it should read like (notice that 'medical' is in the text):
**Check if Products contain Medical and Medical.NetworkType_BuiltInNetwork is "Y"**

I'm only seeing the issue when on the server.  The UI is rendering as expected.

Here's my rule Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><codeeffects xmlns="https://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41" xmlns:ui="https://codeeffects.com/schemas/ui/4"><rule id="31be4f36-26c0-423b-a178-c2d04ab8ca4c" webrule="5.1.16.4" utc="2024-03-12T22:12:52.4714" type="Models.Root, Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" eval="true"><definition><and><condition type="contains"><property name="Products" /><value type="Models.Enums+ProductType, Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">1</value></condition><condition type="equal" stringComparison="OrdinalIgnoreCase"><property name="Medical.NetworkType_BuiltInNetwork" /><value>Y</value></condition></and></definition><format><lines /></format></rule></codeeffects>
```

Here's a simplified version of my model:

```
    public class Root
    {
        public List<Enums.ProductType>? Products { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

and a simplified version of my enum:

```
        public enum ProductType
        {
            [Description("Medical"), EnumItem("Medical")] Medical = 1,
            [Description("RX"), EnumItem("RX")] Rx = 2,
            [Description("Dental"), EnumItem("Dental")] Dental = 3,
            [Description("Vision"), EnumItem("Vision")] Vision = 4,
            [Description("COBRA"), EnumItem("COBRA")] Cobra = 5,
        }
```

Am I'm doing something wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated.